# Accessing a private variable through static method in java

Tags: java, static-methods, private-members

Let say I have the following java classes:
Class A:

```
public class A { 
    private int x; 

    public A(int x){ 
        this.x = x; 
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        A a = new A(1); 
        B b = new B(1,2); 
        System.out.println((A)b.x);
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B extends A { 
    public int y; 

    public B(int x, int y){ 
        super(x); 
        this.y = y; 
    } 
}
```

Why does the compiler marks the access to x on this line

```
System.out.println((A)b.x);
```

as an error, even though I'm trying to access x from the class in which it is defined?

Is it because of:
1. the use of polymorphism?
2. the use of a static method?
3. the use of the main method?

Comment: As the correct answer is listed below, I'd just seriously advise using getters and setters.

Comment: No need to cast B to A,Even if you cast you cant access private members.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make it `((A)b).x` to properly type cast it

Note : You are trying to type cast the property `x` to type `A`. That's the error!

Answer (score 1):

`int x` is `private` therefore it can't be reached from outside of the scope of the class. You could mark it as `protected`. This way it will still have limited scope. Classes that extend A will be able to access the variable freely.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the dot operator has precedence over the cast operator. This will work, because it forces the cast operator to be applied before the dot operator:

```
System.out.println(((A)b).x);
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/6dFnAN)

Answer (score 1):

When you write `(A)b.x`, the compiler try to cast `b.x` into `A`, but `x` is an `int`

Moreover, you don't need to cast `b` into `A` and you can't access `b.x` because `x` is a private field.
You may need a getter for this, like `b.getX()`

Answer (score 1):

You have follwing issues

- Compiler will show `"Field not visible"` Error,Because you trying to access private method of parent class
- Syntactically`.` operator has  precedence over cast operator
- And another impotent thing is that **No need to cast a child object to parent** to access parent specific members, Because they are already inherited to the child, Here the member you are accessing is `private` ,which is not inherited. Even if you cast to parent you cant access private members using child object.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to cast an `int` into `A`. You need to wrap the cast around the object and then call `.x`.

Your call is equivalent to `(A)(b.x)`, when it should be `((A)b).x`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    A a = new A(1); 
    B b = new B(1,2); 
    System.out.println(((A)b).x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, two issues exist here.

One being that `int x` is `private` so it cannot be accessed from the sub-class.

Now even if you change the access criteria of `int x` to `public`or `protected`; the code will still not work because `(A)b.x` will try to typecast an integer (read `x`) to an object (read `A`). Instead of this, you should use `((A)b).x`